# How to show superscript and subscript from web service in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilabel, afnetworking, nsattributedstring

Currently I'm working on an academic app, where I need to handle nearly 1000 mathematical formulas. So, I have prepared an excel sheet with all the formulas in it. Most of the formula has subscript and superscript characters. I have uploaded the excel file in my web service. I'm using AFNetworking to hit the service and get the values. Now, while getting the values, the superscript and subscript words are not displayed correctly. For example, x square is displayed as x2. But I want it as x superscript 2. How to get the values correctly from the service and show it in my UILabel.

Ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This person had an interesting solution: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/display-complex-mathematical-equations-in-ios-5-0-devices

When writing a mathematics paper, you would usually want to use something like LaTeX, but it looks like it is a bit difficult to integrate with Objective-C (you need a UIWebView and use HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to know that you can superscript numbers easily in UTF-8 and they will render properly on your device (as long as you don't pick a font that doesn't like them).

Check this reference: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/superscripts_and_subscripts/utf8test.htm